# How to anonymize the IP in Analytics from Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I've got a Firebase-Newbie question: While integration Firebase in an iOS application, I was asked to use Analytics'

```
_anonymizeIp()
```

from the Firebase object. Is this possible or conceptually invalid? Any hints appreciated.

Best regards,
Marcus

Answer (score 17, accepted):

IP Addresses are currently anonymized by Firebase Analytics.  There is no need/method to explicitly do so.

However, nothing guarantees that we anonymize these in Firebase's [API design](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/) or [terms of service](https://firebase.google.com/terms/). Given that it's just an implementation detail, you should be careful if you are trying to rely on this for any sort of legal compliance or to meet your company's privacy policies.

The docs and APIs are updated frequently and you should keep an eye on them, as well as the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases), for changes.

Comment: I can confirm this after talking to Google's support.

Comment: @SteveGanem, given that this could change at any time, if it did, would a method be provided to continue anonymizing the IPs? (I'm asking from an Android perspective) and is the current 'automatic' IP anonymization in Google Analytics for Firebase documented anywhere? Thanks!

Comment: Finally found in [Firebase Help](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9019185?hl=en) that "IP anonymization is automatically enabled for App+Web properties when you..." @Zippy